# How to (or Can I) use Google Maps in a Desktop application

Tags: api, google-maps, licensing

I researched this, read the TOS and only got more confused. I want to develop a desktop application (Java or Objective-C) using maps. What I'll actually need from the maps is to visually set a starting point, and an end point and get the distance in km. How can I do this (API or interface), and am I allowed to use Google Maps API in this manner?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google maps API needs an Iframe.  So you'd have to embed a browser in your app.  At which point it 'should' not violate the license.  The API and the related is http://code.google.com/apis/maps/.  There is a discussion forum there as well to ask License specific questions.

There are specific API calls to do exactly what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, from that website's FAQ, I got:

Can I use Google Maps in my non-Web application?

> Yes, the Google Maps APIs can now be used in Desktop applications, provided that they adhere to the other restrictions of the Terms of Service. Note that in order for a desktop application to be deemed "publicly accessible", there must be a publicly accessible webpage from which it can be downloaded. See Section 7.1c of the Terms of Service for more information.

Now I only need to find out how to implement it in a desktop!